# how to mock xcom to test airflow python callable tasks?

Tags: airflow, python-unittest

Airflow has built-in dag and task test support but its not sufficient to test tasks in a manner where not all tasks need to be executed.

The goal is to test python callables. It can be done through unittest or any other library but xcom between the callables is an issue.

How to mock xcom so the functions xcom_pull and xcom_push are simulated as expected in the callables?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import Mock

class Tasks(TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        """setup context mock passed to python callable"""
        self.context = dict()
        self.context['ti'] = Mock()
        self.xcom = XCom()
        self.context['ti'].xcom_pull.side_effect = self.xcom.side_effect
        return super().setUp()

    def test_tasks(self):
        # testing python callable functions foo and cat

        # if foo requires return value from another task 
        # through xcom_pull(task_ids='bar') 
        self.xcom.args(5, task_ids = 'bar')

        # if foo requires xcom_pull(task_ids='bar', key='joe')
        self.xcom.args(7, task_ids = 'bar', key = 'joe')

        result = foo(**self.context)
        # test the result e.g
        self.assertTrue(result)

        # if python callable e.g cat, needs to be chained and
        # needs xcom_push values from foo
        self.xcom.xcom_push(self.context['ti'].xcom_push.call_args_list,'foo')
        # and to get the return value using xcom_pull(task_ids='foo')
        self.xcom.args(result, task_ids='foo')

        result = cat(**self.context)
        self.assertTrue(result)
```

below are dependencies for the above test

```
def foo(**context):
    ti = context['ti']

    assert ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='bar') == 5
    assert ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='bar', key='joe') == 7

    ti.xcom_push(key='doe', value=7)

    return True

def cat(**context):
    ti = context['ti']

    assert ti.xcom_pull(key='doe', task_ids='foo') == 7
    assert ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='foo')

    return True

class XCom:
    """mocks xcom"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.map=[]
        self.last_args_index = 0

    def side_effect(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """mock xcom_pull"""

        for result, sig in self.map:
            if sig == kwargs:
                return result
            
        raise Exception('signature not found')
    
    def args(self, result, **kwargs):
        """appending data to simulate xcom_pull"""

        self.map.append((result, kwargs))

    def xcom_push(self, call_args_list, task):
        """saving xcom_push data"""

        for args in call_args_list[self.last_args_index:len(call_args_list)]:
            result = args.kwargs.pop('value')
            kwargs = dict()
            kwargs['task_ids'] = task
            kwargs.update(args.kwargs)
            self.args(result, **kwargs)
            self.last_args_index += 1
```